# Split ArrayList<ProductBean> using particular value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

facing problem on Splitting `ArrayList<ProductBean>` using particular value like

```
ArrayList<ProductBean> al =new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
```

here `ProductBean` is Getter & Setter class which contains several fields like  productId, productName, productPrice, shopId etc. **suppose**

```
                           (productId, productName, productPrice, shopId)
                           -------------------------
 ProductBean s1=new ProductBean(101,"Pantene Shampoo","10 rs.",23);  
  ProductBean s2=new ProductBean(102,"Himalaya Fasewash","80 rs.",21);  
  ProductBean s2=new ProductBean(103,"Dettol Bath soap","30 rs.",25);  
  ProductBean s2=new ProductBean(104,"Dove Bath soap","30 rs.",25);  
  ProductBean s2=new ProductBean(105,"Santoor Bath soap","20 rs.",25);  
  //creating arraylist  
  ArrayList<ProductBean> al=new ArrayList<ProductBean>();  
  al.add(s1);//adding ProductBean class object  
  al.add(s2);  
  al.add(s3);
```

`ArrayList` have multiple product data with same or different `shopId` this means
suppose I've 5 different products in which 2 product have same `shopId` remaining have different shopId.

Now I want to separate `ArrayList` with different `shopId` as shown in code snippet with same shopId 25 and remaining 21, 23 which results in 3 different arraylist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `HashMap`

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ProductBean>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

then add product with Id to map like

```
map.put(id,list);//ArrayList<ProductBean>
```

Update the list for same Id's by getting the list from map and reinsert updated list for same Id

Do all this in `asynctsk` if you have long list of `productbean`

Comment: thanks for reply mate will you elaborate what you try here

Comment: you have to create hashmap with `shopId` as key. Each key will hold arraylist of `ProductBean` with same `shopId`. While creating a map you look for shopId key match inside map if found you get saved list maped to key then update the list by adding new  `ProductBean` to list and reinsert it to map against `shopId key`

Comment: In addition to what prashant17 has said, you can have a common method to add product which will add it to the required list from the map, and a get method with shop Id which will return the required list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the filter operation on a stream then remove the newly collected list values from the original.

```
final List<ProductBean> first = al.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getShopId().equals(25))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
al.removeAll(first);

//repeate for other values you wish to split
```

Comment: thnks for answer but .stream() require API level 24 my minAPI level is 21 so it may be not working on lower than 24 API